# Get google OAuth 2.0 refresh token using PassPortJS and Node.jS

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am having trouble getting a refresh token from Google using Passport JS.  I have been removing access in my account permissions to make sure it is a first time login. I keep getting "undefined" for the token.  Here is the code I have at the moment.

```
Passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    clientSecret: "xxxxx",
    callbackURL: `https://localhost:${port}/auth/google/callback`,
    accessType: 'offline',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req,accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    var tokens = {
      access_token: accessToken,
      refresh_token: refreshToken
    }
    console.log(tokens)
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);


    done(err = false, user = true)


}));
```

If anyone has experience working OAuth into their web apps that could lend a hand it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was in requesting it during the innitail route and creating the consent prompt each time.

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google',{accessType: 'offline', prompt: 'consent', scope: ['openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']}))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the refresh token using passportJS in NodeJS you simply have to add 2 more access fields `( accessType: 'offline', prompt: 'consent' )` in the router section.

```
ex.router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'       
}));
```

After that you will receive a refresh token.

Note: If your application is not verified by the Google then it will so you warning.
Simply click on the *advance* button below and you are ready to go.